# objective c: wait until xml download is complete

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, download, wait

in my app I am downloading an xml from a url. I am then checking a sessionID within that xml. If the sessionID is 0 it means there was an error, if not then a UILabel is updated to say "SUCCESS".. But the problem is: it seems as if the app quickly jumps to checking the xml before it has finished downloading. I say this because it works sometime and sometimes it does not. How can I make the app wait until the xml has finished downloading and has been checked, them set the UILabel (if my assumption of the problem is true)

Comment: How are you currently downloading XML then parsing it ? Show us your code.

Comment: it seems I was doing something else wrong, i was converting the session variable from an NSString to an int yet it contains alphabetic characters (have no idea why I was doing that). Have fixed that by keeping it as an NSString and comparing using isEqualTo:..  I have also implemented Inder's suggestion and is working perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have async request. 
Try checking xml in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //check your xml here and update your label
}
```

Comment: mhhhh, didn't think about that one. Thanks for that.  let me try it out and update you !

Comment: Great I have implemented your suggestion with help from Apple's [developer's library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) on NSURLConnection. I was also doing something else wrong which may have been the culprit (see my reply to 0x8badf00d).. Thanks dude

Comment: 0x8badf00d is the name displayed for the person who commented on my question. Like mine says pnizzle, his says 0x8badf00d..